# Selective data saving to a file in Python

Tags: python

I am defining a Fibonacci sequence and saving the data to a file. However, I would like to save only the distinct sequence, not the repeating ones. For example, `[0,1]` should be saved only once and not three times. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    sequence = [0, 1]  
    while len(sequence) < n:  
        next_number = sequence[-1] + sequence[-2]  
        sequence.append(next_number)  
    return sequence


n = 10
for i in range(0,n): 
    result = fibonacci(i)
    print(result)
    
    with open("Fibonacci.txt", 'a') as f: 
        f.writelines('\n') 
        f.write(str(result))
    print(result)
```

The current saved data is

```
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
```

The data I expect to save

```
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
```

Comment: You can use `set` datastructure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new variable `last_result` that stores the previous iteration value and use an `If` to check it:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    sequence = [0, 1]  
    while len(sequence) < n:  
        next_number = sequence[-1] + sequence[-2]  
        sequence.append(next_number)  
    return sequence

last_result = None
n = 10
for i in range(0,n): 
    result = fibonacci(i)
    print(result)
    
    if result != last_result:
        last_result = result
        with open("Fibonacci.txt", 'a') as f: 
           f.writelines('\n') 
           f.write(str(result))
        print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your starting array `sequence` already has the first 2 values of the fibonacci sequence. Hence you need to start your loop at 2, skipping 0 and 1.

```py
for i in range(2, n):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To save only the distinct Fibonacci sequences, you can modify your code to keep track of the previously generated sequences and check if the current sequence is already present before saving it to the file.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    sequence = [0, 1]  
    while len(sequence) < n:  
        next_number = sequence[-1] + sequence[-2]  
        sequence.append(next_number)  
    return sequence


n = 10
distinct_sequences = []  # Keep track of distinct sequences

for i in range(n):
    result = fibonacci(i)

    if result not in distinct_sequences:
        distinct_sequences.append(result)

        with open("Fibonacci.txt", 'a') as f: 
            f.writelines('\n') 
            f.write(str(result))
    
print(distinct_sequences)
```